# Error "invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)" executing script from Delphi

Tags: delphi, firebird, error-code

I'm developing an Update APP with Delphi 10. I'm running Windows 7 64x, FireBird 2.5.1.26351 32x.

**Execution Order:**

- Checks the current version(select statement from Firebird DataBase)
- Downloads the Update(via FTP)
- Apply it(.exe files, and execute .sql)

Error Code -901 pops out when I try to execute .SQL files. I know that there is an incompatibility issue with W7 64x and FDB 32x, but, I can do everything: Backup and Restore(gbak), DB Commands(all). I tried with FDB 64x instead, and its not working.

**Code:**

```
//Components
FDWaitCursor: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
FDDriverLink: TFDPhysFBDriverLink;
FDConnection:TFDConnection;
FDScript: TFDScript;

function TTHR_Script.CreateComponents:boolean;
begin
  try
  FDDriverLink := TFDPhysFBDriverLink.Create(FDDriverLink);
  FDWaitCursor := TFDGUIxWaitCursor.Create(FDWaitCursor);

  FDConnection := TFDConnection.Create(FDConnection);
    with FDConnection do
    begin
      DriverName := 'FB';
      Params.UserName := THRBanco.BDUser;
      Params.Password := THRBanco.BDPass;
      Params.Database := THRBanco.DIROrigem;
    end;

  FDScript := TFDScript.Create(FDScript);
    with FDScript do
    begin
      Connection := FDConnection;
      OnConsolePut := FDScript_ConsolePut;
    end;
  Result := true;
  except on E:Exception do
    begin
      Result := false;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TTHR_Script.ExecLogs;
var
  F : integer;
  SR : TSearchRec;
begin
  F := FindFirst(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\manager\update\logs\*.sql',faArchive,SR);
  FDConnection.Open;

  while F = 0 do
  begin
    with FDScript do
    begin
      SQLScripts.Clear;
      SQLScriptFileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\manager\update\logs\'+SR.Name;
      ValidateAll;
      ExecuteAll;
    end;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    F := FindNext(SR);
  end;
  FDConnection.Close;
end;
```

After installing Firebird 2.5.6, still got the same -901 error. Error Log:

```
update empresa set emp_verbanco='2016.55'; 
[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: Ok [00:00:00.047]. 
[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: update empresa set emp_versis='2016.55'; 
[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: Ok [00:00:00.016]. 
[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: commit work; 
[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: ERROR: Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -901 invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)
```

Comment: try Firebird 2.5.6: http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-6/ your version is a bit old

Comment: Error codes are relatively useless. Some codes cover tens of different (but related) errors. Please post the actual error message, or if you don't have it: the error number (which is different from the error code).

Comment: And also post the SQL script you are trying to execute.

Comment: After installing Firebird 2.5.6, still got the same -901 error.

**Error Log:**

`update empresa set emp_verbanco='2016.55';

[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: Ok [00:00:00.047].
[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: update empresa set emp_versis='2016.55';

[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: Ok [00:00:00.016].
[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: commit work;

[13_09_2016 | 14:29]: ERROR: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -901
invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)`

Comment: I can't post my SQL Script, its too long. Can I post at pastebin, then post it here?

Comment: This script works fine with IBExpert, but it doesnt with TFDScript(FireDac Script Component).

Comment: @RafaelHarth You should edit your answer to include information, not post it as a comment (for example I have edited the logging from your comment into the post). The error indicates that you haven't started a transaction, having things like `commit work` in a script executed through a programming language is usually a red flag, as drivers/programming languages usually handle their own transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you having things like 'COMMIT WORK;' in your sql script.

As per FireDAC documentation:

> Resolving Incompatibilities
>
> Firebird ISQL works in non-autocommit mode. By default, the autocommit mode for TFDScript/TFDConnection is turned on. For better compatibility, set FDConnection.TxOptions.AutoCommit to False before the script execution. Or execute the SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF script command.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Executing_SQL_Scripts_(FireDAC)